# Issue with Dynamic Subheadings at Page Break in pdfmake

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, pdfmake

I am using `pdfmake` to render data in Angular. I have five headings in each page:

1. i have a tenant
2. inside the tenant, i have activities
3. inside the activities i have materials

I need to render like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuUCY.png)

```
      4            3         4                 5
```

Here when the page breaks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rbVg.png)

It's taking the first activity value in the second PDF. I need to render the second activity where the page breaks.

```js
generatePdf() {
  const documentDefinition = {
    pageSize: 'A4',
    pageOrientation: 'landscape',
    content: [    
    this.generateReport04Structure()
    ]
    
    
    
    
    
    generateReport04Structure() {
  const retunData = [];
  this.reports.report04.forEach(element => {
    const data = [];
    data.push(
      {
        margin: [0, 20, 0, 0],
        style: 'tableExample',
        table: {          
          headerRows: 5,
          // pageBreak: 'before',
          dontBreakRows: true,
          body: [
            [
              {text: 'TENANT', style: 'tableHeader', colSpan: 3, border: [false, false, false, false]}, {} , {},
              {text: 'BUILDING', style: 'tableHeader', colSpan: 3, border: [false, false, false, false]}, {}, {},
              {text: 'DATE', style: 'tableHeader', colSpan: 2, border: [false, false, false, false]}, {}
             ],
             [
              {text: element.tenantName, style: 'tableHeader', colSpan: 3, border: [true, true, true, true], bold: true, margin: [3, 6, 0, 10]}, {} , {},
              {text: element.tenantBuilding, style: 'tableHeader', colSpan: 3, border: [true, true, true, true], bold: true, margin: [3, 6, 0, 10]}, {}, {},
              {text: element.inspectionDate, style: 'tableHeader', colSpan: 2, border: [true, true, true, true], bold: true, margin: [3, 6, 0, 10]}, {}
             ],
             ...this.report04ActivityElements(element.activity),
          ],
          // widths: ['8%', '8%', '8%', '8%', '8%', '8%', '8%', '8%'],
          widths: ['12%', '12%', '12%', '12%', '12%', '12%', '12%', '12%'],
          layout: {
            hLineWidth(i, node) {
              return (i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length) ? 0.1 : 0.1;
            },
            vLineWidth(i, node) {
              return (i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length) ? 0.1 : 0.1;
            },
            hLineColor(i, node) {
              return (i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length) ? 'black' : 'black';
            },
            vLineColor(i, node) {
              return (i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length) ? 'black' : 'black';
            },
            paddingTop(i, node) { return 10; },
            paddingBottom(i, node) { return 10; }
          }
        },
      }
    );
    retunData.push(data);
  });
  return retunData;
}



report04ActivityElements(value) {
  let activity = [];
  value.forEach(element => {
    activity.push([
      {text: '', style: 'tableHeader', border: [false, false, false, false], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
      {text: 'ACTIVITY #', style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]} ,
      {text: 'ACTIVITY TYPE', style: 'tableHeader', colSpan: 2, border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]}, {},
      {text: 'DESCRIPTION', style: 'tableHeader', colSpan: 3, border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]}, {}, {},
      {text: 'PRACTICE', style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
    ]);
    let returnData = [];
    returnData.push(
      {text: '', style: 'tableHeader',border: [false, false, false, false], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]} ,
      {text: element.activityNumber, style: 'tableHeader',border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
      {text: element.activityType, style: 'tableHeader', colSpan: 2, border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]}, {},
      {text: element.description, style: 'tableHeader', colSpan: 3, border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]}, {}, {},
      {text: element.practice, style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10] }
    );
    activity.push(returnData);
    if (element.material.length > 0) {
      activity.push(...this.report04Material(element.material));
    }
  });
  return activity;
}




report04Material(value) {  
  let material = [];
  material.push([
    {text: '', border: [false, false, false, false]},
    {text: '', border: [false, false, false, false]},
    {text: 'MATERIAL #', style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
    {text: 'MATERIAL NAME', style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
    {text: 'QUANTITY', style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
    {text: 'CAPACITY', style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
    {text: 'SEC/SPILL CON', style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
    {text: 'LEAK/STAIN', style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]}
  ]);
  value.forEach(element => {
    let returnData = [];
    returnData.push(
      {text: '', border: [false, false, false, false]},
      {text: '', border: [false, false, false, false]},
      {text: element.materialNumber, style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
      {text: element.materialName, style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
      {text:  element.quantity, style: 'tableHeader',  border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
      {text:  element.capacity, style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
      {text:  element.secSpill, style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]},
      {text:  element.leakStain, style: 'tableHeader', border: [true, true, true, true], margin: [3, 8, 0, 10]}        
    );
    material.push(returnData);
  });
  return material;
}
```

Comment: Please help.. any one?